# How to directly edit PFQueryTableViewController's objects NSArray

Tags: ios, parse-platform

simple question, as per the subject: i have no intention of uploading changes to a returned array of PFObjects, but want to purge the array of specific items. Given it is set to readonly, what is the best way to approach this while still using PFQueryTableViewController?

Or is it better to got with a regular tableviewcontroller and lose the benefits of parse's VC?

I am trying to wrap my head around getting the proper data i require but without proper SQL, it seems very very difficult. (lack of Distinct, grouping etc)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: no, i had to rethink the UI and presentation. While the db behind Parse is awesome for some things, the lack of our ability to form coherent SQL to extract exactly what is needed does cause a old-school data modeller headaches ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would override the objectsDidLoad and objectAtIndexPath methods if you want to modify the returned results. See here for a better explanation: https://parse.com/questions/using-pfquerytableviewcontroller-for-uitableview-sections

It's just a good post on overriding the methods in PFQTVC to do different things with the data.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, but this doesn't address the question: i hope to manage the actual objects array and thus allow PFQTVC to continue to be used. My data contains duplicates, and i have an algorithm being called in objectsDidLoad() already. We simply cannot tap into objects itself. 

Perhaps i have missed the ability to locally delete a PFObject. This would work as i do not intend to upload the delete. I will look again.